# Can calculate function be performed on an editable control as well

Tags: orbeon

I am using the calculate attribute for a particular node which is editable to get a default value initially. When the control loads initially the default value is getting populated depending upon the calculate attribute for that particular node. But when i override the default value, the overridden value is not getting binded to that node. Is there any solution for this problem ?

Comment: Vivek, I am not sure you provide enough details.Can you be more specific?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can allow users to edit the value of a node for which you have a calculate. For this, in the `xforms:bind`, explicitly add `readonly="false()"`, as a node for which you specify a `calculate` automatically becomes readonly. If you do this, keep in mind that the `calculate` also runs after users edited the field, so that expression needs to be written in such a way that it doesn't overwrite the value entered by users. Often you would do something like: `calculate="if (. = '') then {some expression} else ."`, not to overwrite what users typed if they did type something.